# how to set domain name for bandwagong host

Tags: django, server, dns

I am trying to deploy my Django project on my new-purchased bandwagong VPS server, to be clarified, I am total a layman to server/network, but I just tried based on my intuition. Everything works smoothly except setting the domain name, I have been bought one domain from resellerclub, however, I have no idea how to combine my domain name and server,  I noticed on the control page it has two keywords `host name` and `DNS` in this picture exactly, since these two keywords information are provided by my domain manager.

[image]

Naturally, I fill the blank, but when I started the server with `0.0.0.0:80`, and visit new domain name `bravopan.com`, it does not appear my project homepage, so I want to ask some network experts how to integrate my domain name and bandwagong server?

Comment: Use [Resellerclub's DNS service](https://manage.resellerclub.com/kb/servlet/KBServlet/faq471.html) to add A Record with 45.78.8.52 as Destination IPv4 Address

Comment: It works. Thanks, Dusan!